# Implement multiple languages in IntelliJ plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, rythm

I'm currently writing an IntelliJ plugin.
This plugin should handle HTML, Java (sometimes also JavaScript) and [rythm](http://rythmengine.org/) (a template engine) I followed the plugin documentation of JetBrains.

My lexer (I use JFlex) matches everything and recognizes the matched code as HTML.

For the rythm code parts I have regular expressions in my lexer.

I also want to implement some Java Language features like the completion of packages and classes.

Also I don't know if my approach is correct. [Because my lexer splits HTML](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203372464-Java-Script-warning-in-custom-language-plugin) at some points:

> @, (, ), {, }

The regex to match the complete code and recognize it as HTML is:

> TEXT = [^@*(){}]+

This regex causes the problem that my HTML Code is splitted at points where the code starts with @, (, ), {, and }
If I don't except these characters my plugin doesn't reconize my other regular expressions and my brace matcher would not work anymore because it would match everything.

Is there a better way to support multiple languages and how do I implement Java language features in my plugin?